# Is their a way to save the locals window variables in a file format [ json ] for each line using VS code Debugger?

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, vscode-debugger

I want to save information of the variables values inside the Locals window for each line of the code. [image: vs code debugger]

I read through vs code docs but weren't able to get any clue, what I want to do is save the variable value at runtime for each line of code ( global + local variables )

My goal :
Is to record the state of variables ( values ) at each line of code and save it to a file to analyze. As their are more than 1000 programs can't do this manually.

Comment: use the Developer Tools, locate the view for the locals, Copy the HTML element and paste it in an HTML file, then write a script that converts this to JSON

Comment: Wow, this is interesting.  I would want to automate this by using a script : input program-> record each line variable value execution using debugger -> save it to file